# Authenticating with PowerShell to Kill Process

Tags: powershell, authentication, terminate, securestring

I would like to be able to run this from different workstations which mean we need to authenticate. I have this below but it doesn't seem to work. Can you see anything wrong.

```
get-content .\killprocess.PS1

$username = 'je\leigh'
$password = cat 'U:\Accounts\Synergy Tools\securestring.txt' | convertto-securestring
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `-argumentlist $username, $password

(Get-Content 'U:\Accounts\Synergy Tools\Computers.txt') | ForEach-Object {Get-WmiObject -computer $_ -class win32_process -filter "name='synergy.exe' or name='booking9.exe' or name='acl_apps.exe' or name='pos.exe' or name='booking.exe'" -credential $cred| %{$_.terminate()} | out-null}
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

If `securestring.txt` contains a readable password E.g. `MyP@ssWord!123`. Try using `ConvertTo-SecureString`'s `-AsPlainText` & `-Force` parameters:

```
$password = Get-Content 'U:\...\securestring.txt' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
```

This will convert the text in `securestring.txt` into a readable `SecureString`, which can be viewed with `$Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString`:

```
01000000d08c9ddf0115d1118c7a00c04fc297eb010000000a65b1b20fe4e0418aece793d7242358
0000000002000000000003660000c00000001000000082e9a55adb7c90d9bed5946aed69e5380000
000004800000a000000010000000932bccf24879272d36536f6ef98e1be4180000006fb092d673a8
1f84b5954f9cb35daee2addb2d325ec25112140000005c8982b4cd15503000796213c3e0d3869780
```

Then just give the `$password` variable straight to `-argumentlist $username, $password`

If you wanted to you could store the output of `ConvertFrom-SecureString` into the `securestring.txt` then use the following in your script:

```
$password = Get-Content 'U:\...\securestring.txt' | ConvertTo-SecureString
```

**Note**: You may get errors if there are more than one line in `securestring.txt` as it will turn `$password` an array of strings.

Comment: @leigh-carmichael if this answer has helped or answered your question please accept it or upvote it.